# Applying entrance and exit animations to an object in powerpoint simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, animation

I've got an image which I would like to animate into a slide, at the click of a mouse, and then have it animate out so that I can replace it with text. I'm trying to add some humor to a rather dull topic, so I want to pop-up a Dilbert cartoon, and then replace it with an actual definition for the term I'm trying to define.

However, when I try to apply an exit animation, it removes the entrance animation from the object and vice-versa.

Is there any way I can obtain this effect, preferably without covering it up with a white rectangle and having that exit from the screen?

I'm using Powerpoint 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've been foiled by bad user interface design.

When you add an animation via Animations | Animation, it wipes out any previously applied animation.

Instead, apply the first animation as you normally would, then use Animations | Advanced Animation | Add Animation button to add further animations.

You'll know it's working when you see more than one numbered gold-colored icons next to the shape you're animating, or the shape name appears more than once in the Animation Pane.